# Alternative to HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest

I have a Silverlight OOB app that uses HttpWebRequest to download files in "chunks" using the range header of HTTP 1.1.

Some of our users have PCs or are using proxies which only support HTTP 1.0 so this header/functionality isn't available. This leads the client to try and download very large files all at once, rather than in smaller "chunks". This greatly impacts the experience on the use of the application and I'd like to implement alternative functionality in this instance.

Unfortunately, Silverlight doesn't support [HttpWebResponse.ProtocolVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.protocolversion%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) so I can't easily detect if the client doesn't support the range header.

Is there a way to detect the version of HTTP which is being used in Silverlight? (Access to the raw HTTP response?)
Or am I going to need to detect this on the server and notify the Silverlight client appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the ClientHTTP stack in Silverlight you can access the `Headers` collection of the response object.  This won't let you detect the protocol version however it should allow you to detect that the "Accept-Ranges" header is present and has the value "bytes".

So a test request to some static no caching resource on the server might allow you to detect whether a range based request would be acceptable.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks Anthony. Hadn't thought of this as my dev server doesn't include the "Accept-Ranges" header, but the live server (CDN) does.